# How to make x += (1 - x) correctly works based on delta time?

Tags: math, time, generic-programming, algebra

Let's say that Time.deltatime can be used to get the real time between the code's update.

So, if I have a **sum** and I want to make it works **based on real-time** I would make this:

```
x += 1;
```

Into this:

```
x += 1 * Time.deltatime;
```

---

**My question is:** how could I do the same thing with this piece of code:

```
x += (1 - x)*0.1;
```

Which is a simple code that I use to smoothly approaches 1.
The problem is that I cannot simply do

```
x += (1 - x)*Time.deltatime
```

Because that obviously would not make it works based on real time.
How should I proceed?

---

Let's pretend that the code is running 4 times per second.
It would go like this if x started at 0.

The code is

```
x += (1 - x)*0.1
```

Results on each step would be:

```
step 1: x = 0.1
step 2: x = 0.19
step 3: x = 0.271
step 4: x = 0.3439
```

How could I achieve this effect in the same way, but running only 2 times per second, like this:

```
step 1: x = 0.19
step 2: x = 0.3439
```

What would be the code then?

Comment: `x += (1 - x)` is the same as `x = 1` (if ignoring overflows)

Comment: Is `Time.deltatime` a real thing in a real programming language you're using, or just something you made up for your example?

Comment: The problem seems to be your "smooth" function, which asymptotically approaches 1 with every step. The assumption here is that every increment with that smooth function makes a unit "step" forward. This assumption breaks down when using real-time delta. What does it mean to make a step 10x longer than another? Unless that is well defined there's no way to answer your question.

Comment: Not necessarily python, just generic code, although I think it works pretty much like the Time.deltatime from Unity C#. And It is x += (1 - x)*value

Answer (score 0):

If you consider your series as a function `f(t)` where `t` is the iteration count, then

```
f(t) = 1 - 0.9^t
```

Here `^` is the power operator.

So if we assume that a time delta of 1 corresponds to your original series, you can use this formula:

```
x := 1 - (1 - x) * 0.9^deltatime
```